# Google Drive API v3 uploads 'Untitled' file every time I try to upload something with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, drive

So the drive documentation is for NodeJs and i'm using plain JS. I can upload with no problem however the files appear to be uploaded incorrectly as 'Untitled' and unopenable

```
var file = document.getElementById('input-file').files[0];

var fileMetadata = {
    'parents': ['0AN75N3P23eTJUk9PVA'], // Folder ID at Google Drive
    'name':
        cliente + '.' + file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) // Filename at Google Drive
};
var r = new FileReader();
r.readAsText(file);
r.onload = function (e) {
    var body = r.result;
    var media = {
        mimeType: file.type,
        body: body
    };


    gapi.client.drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media,
        fields: 'id'
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('response: ', response);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log('something is wrong');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file is untitled because you are not properly setting the name of the file.  Its cant be opened because you have not properly set the mime type.

Try testing it supplying the name and the mime type hard coded.  Then once that works you can figure out what is wrong with your building of the name and file.type methods.

```
let fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'icon.png',
        'parents':  [  '10krlloIS2i_2u_ewkdv3_1NqcpmWSL1w'  ]
    };

let media = {
        mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
        body: fs.createReadStream('icon.png')
    };
```

Comment: I did it and the file was still uploaded as untitled.

Comment: are you sure its the same file if you keep running it tis going to keep uploading a new file your doing create not update